# DrawPolygon works, but FillPolygon doesn't using the same set of points

Tags: c++, graphics, mfc, gdi+

I have a vector of points where each point represents the vertices of a polygon. If I use the vector of points in the DrawPolygon method, the polygon is drawn as expected. However, If I use the same vector with FillPolygon, nothing happens.

Here is how I am successfully drawing the outline of a polygon:

```
void CBurstSign::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics)
{
    Pen pen(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
    graphics->DrawPolygon(&pen, &mPoints[0], mPoints.size());
}
```

This works. Making a couple of minor adjustments, I thought the following changes would draw a filled polygon:

```
void CBurstSign::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics)
{
    SolidBrush backgroundBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
    graphics->FillPolygon(&backgroundBrush, &mPoints[0], mPoints.size());
}
```

When this code is ran, nothing is drawn.

I even tried using an array of points instead of a vector like the documentation shows, but this fails as well:

```
void CBurstSign::Draw(Gdiplus::Graphics* graphics)
{
    Gdiplus::PointF points[65] = {};
    SolidBrush backgroundBrush(Color(255, 255, 0, 0));
    int i = 0;
    for (PointF point : mPoints)
    {
        points[i] = point;
        i++;
    }
    PointF* pPoints = points;
    graphics->FillPolygon(&backgroundBrush, pPoints, mPoints.size());
}
```

I cannot see what I'm missing here. The array of points is the same in either case, so I'm not sure why DrawPolygon would work but FillPolygon wouldn't.

Comment: No idea, but maybe re-using the first point, to make it clear you are CLOSING the loop?

Comment: Are you using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-fillpolygon(inconstbrush_inconstpointf_inint_infillmode)?  Maybe the 4th parameter, which you do not supply is picking a default you don't want?  What is the return value, which you are currently not capturing?

Comment: `FillPolygon` returns a [Status](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplustypes/ne-gdiplustypes-status) code you aren't evaluating. @nei [FillPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-fillpolygon(inconstbrush_inconstpointf_inint_infillmode)) will always produce a closed shape: *"If the last point and the first point do not coincide, they specify the last side of the polygon."*

Comment: @NeilGatenby It was the fill mode. Turns out there are 2 options, and by default, the 2nd one is chosen. Changing it to the first option works. I have never had this issue, and don't specify the fill mode in other places in the project. Thank you so much.